# How to create new state for every value in state array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, state

My state looks like this

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
    bpm: [],
    price: null,
    genreTypeId: [],
    filters: [{}],
  });
```

I would like to create an object inside filters for every  value in bpm or genreTypeId. Is this possible?

so this is what I would like my state to look like after values inserted.

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
    bpm: [126,78],
    price: null,
    genreTypeId: [1],
    filters: [{bpm: 126, price: null, genreTypeId: 1},
             {bpm: 76, price: null, genreTypeId: 1}],
  });
```

Comment: This sounds like the type of thing that would be faster to try out and see if it works, than to ask people if it works.

Comment: What is the relationship between `bpm` and `genreTypeId`? What happens if there is one element in the former and multiple elements in the latter?

Comment: Looks like you're overcomplicating your state graph. Consider doing something like `const [bpm, setBpm] = useState([]); const [price, setPrice] = useState(null); ...etc.`.

Comment: @223seneca there is no relationship between the two. They just hold values that I can refer back to for the new filters state

Comment: @HereticMonkey I can already setState to bpm,price and genretypeId. the states are just placeholders for me to hold values that I could shape into the object array in filters

Comment: It doesn't make sense to create an object `for every value in bpm or genreTypeId`. Think in terms of what is going to get looped over. Your example seems to show looping over `bpm` and then using the single element of `genreTypeId` in each of those loops.

Comment: But when you call `setState`, you replace the object. If you use separate variables you can easily call `setBpm([126,78])` knowing you won't affect any of the other state properties. See [React's own FAQ](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-one-or-many-state-variables) Obviously it's your choice (I did say "Consider"), but as your app grows, you may find it easier to maintain state if it's broken out. Up to you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly that you want to loop over both `bpm` and `genreTypeId`, try this (pulling off the real state instead of the hardcoded `state` object in my example):

```
const state = {
    bpm: [126, 78],
    price: null,
    genreTypeId: [1, 2],
    filters: []
  }

const filters = []
const { bpm, genreTypeId } = state

if (bpm.length > 0) {
  bpm.forEach(cadence => {
    genreTypeId.forEach(id => {
      filters.push({bpm: cadence, price: null, genreTypeId: id})
    }
  }
} else {
  genreTypeId.forEach(id => {
    // Please note that the following line is just showing an example of when bpm is an empty array, which technically isn't the case here
    filters.push({bpm: [], price: null, genreTypeId: id})
  }
}

const [state, setState] = useState({
    bpm: [126, 78],
    price: null,
    genreTypeId: [1, 2],
    filters
  })
```

Comment: this feels like it's on the right track however filters.push doesn't happen unless genreTypeId and bpm has values, is there a way for them to be independent?

Comment: Updated my answer. What about that?

Comment: I would need bpm,price and genretypeid to be able to push to filter independently. Is that still possible with forEach?

Comment: That is not the question you asked. You may wish to update your original question.

Comment: Does this work for you? If so, feel free to accept the answer.